# Crop Binary Image on Object Height and Width

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I have this image:
[character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcPyo.png)

I have successfully isolated the character, and now I want to crop the image to bounds of the binary object. Here is the cleaned up image that I want to crop: [edited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CdrR.png)

I can't seem to figure out the code. Here is what I've tried:

```
inv = cv2.bitwise_not(img)
mask = np.zeros(img.shape, np.uint8)
_, cnts, hier = cv2.findContours(img.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for c in cnts:
    if cv2.contourArea(c) > 100:
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], 0, 255, -1)
        x, y, h, w = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        roi = mask[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        crop = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        final = crop * (roi / 255)
```

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: How to crop the second posted image above to the edge of the black/white region?

Comment: this isn't your code, right? Have you tried to go through it step by step and see what happens?

Comment: to the answerers: you don't even need to compute the contours. Just compute the bounding box of the white points in `inv`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to crop an image with the points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2)

```
(x1,y1)+-------+
       |       |
       |       |
       +-------+(x2,y2)
## mask is a numpy array (an image)
croped_image = mask[y1:y2, x1:x2] ## this will return a cropped image
```

but for your question you want the bounding rectangle to crop the binary image i guess

see : https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html

```
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours( mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE )
contour        = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)
x, y, w, h     = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
x1, y1, x2, y2 = x, y, x+w, y+h
```

now use these points to crop the image

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use max to find the largest contour and `cv2.boundingRect` to find the coordinates of the largest contour after which you can crop it.

```
c = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
```

It would be better to use `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL` instead of `cv2.RETR_LIST` while using `cv2.findContours` as in this case as it you are looking for only the boundry of the object and not internal details.